# Meteor update a deployed app with signed APK

Tags: android, meteor

I made an app using Meteor.
I deployed it, and made it ready to deploy it to the Play Store using this tutorial: https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-android

Now I found a bug, so I want to update the app.

Do I have to start all over again now with creating new .apk files? Or is using `meteor deploy MyAppName.meteor.com` enough? Or is there some fast way to update the .apk files?

Yours,
L

Comment: I have a similar query. The only mistake I did was I used the keygenerator again and deleted my old key. Is there a way I can still update the apk on play store?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to sign your app using the key I have already used for the first app publishing.
That is, you do not use keygenerator again just skip this step and sign the app by already generated file.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I only have to repeat this step: `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 unaligned.apk your-app-name`

Comment: Even if you just update the deployed app, then the android app will use the hot-code-push to update/load the latest version. But I strongly recommend to sign new apk with the same key and publish it, Since there is a reloading of your app occurs when the app uses hot-code-push.

Comment: I have a similar query. The only mistake I did was I used the keygenerator again and deleted my old key. Is there a way I can still update the apk on play store?

Comment: @user3807691 if you already saved your key somewhere, you can.

Comment: yes, i have my old key, but i just copied the key from my .jks file and saved it as a string somewhere else. Now how i can i edit my new .jks file and replace the new key with the old